# How do I reference tags in a when statement in Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, ansible

Given this task, particularly in the when statement, what is the way to reference the following tag:

```
 "tags": {
    "Name": "volume1"
  },
```

Task:

```
  - name: Attach correct ebs volume to correct instance using tags
    local_action:
        module: ec2_vol
        region: '{{ region }}'  
        instance: "{{ item.instance_ids[0] }}"
        id: vol-1111111111111111
        name: ebs-volume1
        device_name: /dev/sdf
    with_items: '{{ ec2.results }}' 
    when:
    - item.instance_ids[0] is defined
    - item.tagged_instances.tags.Name == "volume1"
```

I get an error back saying that there is no attribute "tags".

I can't seem to reference it correctly in a debug statement either.

I am thinking it could be something like:

item.tagged_instances.tags == "Name": "volume1"

Should I have curly brackets??

Thanks!

Nick

Comment: You can always `debug: var=item` to inspect it's content and available properties. I doubt that `tagged_instances` will be there.

Comment: after using debug: var=item to inspect it I thought it was all ok, but then I realized that there was one iteration of the item that did not have tagged_instances. Thanks! I was only looking at what was working, not the part of the debug that was not...

Comment: ...I had a when statement on my debug that was skipping something that my task was not...thanks again

Comment: Turns out you were even more right than I thought...tagged_instances[0] was the real answer to accessing the variables underneath it because in the debug output it had a [ sign which means it is a list!

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer for those that need it:

when: **item.tagged_instances[0].tags.Name == "volume1"**

This ensures that the task only works on the instances that have a tag of volume1. Pretty neat. In this case the key was Name and the value was volume1.

Thanks!